# Consulta sobre interaccion con servidor

Tags: php, html

Tengo una duda, me gustaría me la pudieran aclarar de manera sencilla. xfavor

Por ejemplo. Para el back end de un formulario de correo electrónico, como el PHPmailer. Simple ejemplo.
Únicamente se utiliza PHP para hacer esta función?
O hay algun otro lenguaje o método que reemplace a PHP en general?

No se si me explico.

Comment: Como dato, es que voy comenzando a investigar todo lo relacionado con programación web. Se los agradecería

Comment: Para backend hay mas lenguajes con los que puedes hacer lo mismo, ejemplos son python, ruby, java y muchos mas.

Comment: PHPmailer es una libreria de PHP, asi que no se a que te refieres con la pregunta en realidad.